# #define equivalent in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I got this line of code that I'm repeating a lot where I declare a variable as `DEV_BROADCAST_HDR` and give it a value based in the systems events.

Since I need to wait until the event, I can't declare this as a global or similar, so I was wondering if there's some way to do something like `#Define` in C++:

```
#Define MyLineOfCode Dim foo As DEV_BROADCAST_HDR = DirectCast(Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, GetType(DEV_BROADCAST_HDR)), DEV_BROADCAST_HDR)
```

Is this possible in Visual Basic 2010?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, #Const seems to do the trick.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/directives/const-directive

Answer (score 0):

No, it’s not possible. Visual Basic .NET has nothing like C’s `#define` at all. The closest you’ll get is find and replace in your editor.

Consider instead using a proper function. You could even make it generic:

```vb
Function StructFromPointer(Of T)(p As IntPtr) As T
    Return DirectCast(Marshal.PtrToStructure(p, GetType(T)), T)
End Function
```